# How to 'preselect' text in a TextField so that typing something new immediately replaces the previous text?

Tags: codenameone

It is common practice in many UI situations to preselect the text displayed in a text editing field in such a way that if the user starts typing it immediately replaces the displayed text.

This can be useful for example in search field to show the previously searched text (for reuse or editing) while making it easy to search for a new text string simply by start typing.

I've searched for how to do this in TextField, but not found a way yet - is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have a concept of pre-select and it isn't common in mobile where selection is awkward by comparison. A more common approach here is to have an X button next to the text field which clears the text field instantly. You can easily do it by just adding a button next to the field.

Comment: The use case the user described seems much more like a desktop app than a smartphone mobile app. In the latter case, to allow the user to immediately enter text in a TextField, maybe the `startEditingAsync()` method can be a solution, it will open the virtual keyboard. In the case of a desktop app, maybe the `requestFocus()` method might be useful, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I already have a (x) to clear the field, but that means two operations to start searching for new text: clear, then type new text. With preselected text it would only require one operation: type.

Comment: And it will give a better UX because if the user doesn't notice there is text already, the new text replaces the previous and is immediately used. Whereas without preselection, it is easy not to notice the previous text and what you type is added to it - not what you'd expect.  I believe one reason this is uncommon on mobile platforms is that they often don't store the previously searched text. This makes a simpler UI, but painful if you need to type in the same text each time you redo the previous search.

Comment: Mobile platforms also use auto-complete suggestions in such cases which is a strategy you can adopt

Comment: Auto-complete would be a good solution for selecting between past search strings, so an interesting idea. However, my objective here was to both keep the last search string, AND avoid the extra click to clear the field (and the annoying side effect when you forget to clear, that you need to clear the whole field and reenter the new search text). There is really no trick in TextField to programmatically select the text? When you select the text now, is it handled at OS-level?

Comment: No. Selection is very different between OS's and isn't as common of a paradigm in mobile